# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: for external C library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c

I downloaded a C library for an audio codec, I compile it and add it to my project.

Now, every time I try to use it it gives me a Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: error when I try to call one of the methods of the library.

What could it be the problem? Do I need to compile the library specific for armv7?

Comment: please paste complete messgae error

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_opus_encoder_create", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o

Comment: Try to change architecture in your build settings from architecture arm7s to architecture arm7, just delete s suffix and see whats happens. It will not solve your target architecture problem, but enable you to run the project in the meantime.

Comment: I just used ./configure and make, I dont know how to compile specific for amrv7. The same happens if I use the simulator, it says the same msg but for i386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have set up your XCode project such that is compiles for both the `armv7` and `armv7s` architecture (note that **s** at the end). However, the project for the C library is only compiled for `armv7`.

To fix, either change the library project so that it compiles for both architectures as well, or change the app project to only compile for `armv7`.

I'd go for the second option as there is currently no need for `armv7s` support and very few devices out that can use it.

**Update:**

If your getting the same message for the simulator as well, then your library project isn't compiled for 'i386' neither (which is required for the simulator only). It indicates that your C library project isn't set up at all for compiling for multiple architectures. So the second option (and not using the simulator) is the easiest approach.

Comment: It's happening the same with armv7, how do I compile it for those archs?

Comment: I guess you need to analyze what the *configure* and *make* are exactly doing. It seems they compile the library for your Mac and not for the iPhone or the iPhone simulator. Do you have any documentation that indicates support for the iPhone?